# How to graph a function involving limits?

Tags: calculus, limits, graphing-functions

The given function is :

$f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{1+x^n}$  $ ;(x \ge 0)$

The function variable is $x$ and not $n$. This seems strange to me.
All I can think of is that $f(x)$ is a family of curves which depends on the parameter $n$ and when $n\to \infty$ will the family of curves converge to a single curve? If so how to find it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the value of the limit for each (fixed) $x$. For example, $f(0) = 1$. I don't want to give away the question entirely, but I suggest you use the 'binomial' expansion for general powers (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem), for example). Since you want a large-$n$ limit, you don't need to be really precise but can collect terms into $\mathcal{O}(1/n)$, or such. Note that you have to be careful to apply the $(1+z)^r$ expansion for $z < 1$. For $x > 1$, and hence $x^n > 1$, you should think about how to overcome this.

If you need a further hint, feel free to ask! :)

Answer (score 0):

If $x>1$, $x^n$ will go to infinity for large $n$, so $1$ can be neglected. Therefore $f(x)=x$ for $x>1$. If $x\lt 1$, $x^n$ goes to zero, so it can be neglected. $f(x)=1$ for $x\lt 1$ The first 
[search result](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&q=plot+(1%2Bx%5E5)%5E0.2&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) in google is a graph of a function. Search for "plot (1-x^5)^0.2"

Comment: Dude, you just spoilt that question for him/her totally. How is s/he going to learn if s/he just gets given the answer straight off?